# Changing "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." when the duplicate was posted before

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, wording

From time to time, a question A is closed as a duplicate of question B, even though B was asked after A.

I find the closure message misleading:

> This question has been asked **before** and already has an answer.

Could we change the message so that it doesn't claim A was asked after B?